# How to share Ubuntu terminal GUI screen from current network to different network?

Tags: 14.04

I want to give direct remote connection of Ubuntu terminal through the VPN. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a terminal. Use a ssh connection. Install `ssh` on both machines via

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

`ssh` is a meta-package, that contains the client and the server.

and connect via

```
ssh user@host
```

Comment: He would also need ssh-server on host

Comment: @prakharsingh95 As I wrote "on both machines"

Comment: I forgot. I typically install client and server separately. Been a while since I used Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear as to whether you want the terminal as in the command line or the terminal as in the computer--terminal could mean either. Regardless, the answer to your question is yes; you can remotely connect to a terminal over VPN.

As A.B notes, you can use `ssh`, which definitely the easiest way to use the command line remotely. If you want to work with the GUI session and not the command line, there are many utilities available. One is **NX Technology**, which is a cross platform remote desktop standard that
operates over a modified SSH session. You can find more information about it on the web; I found out about it from http://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/33444/DePoy_DR_T_2012.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y.

Comment: suppose, one is server and multiple terminal's in 'A' network and we are accessing from 'B' Network to 'A' network's terminal. At 'A' Network we are configured 4 terminal for take remote only from remotely. these 4 machine can access data from Server but from remote machine to 'B' Network don't share data via internet. how?